# When are two neural networks independent from each other?

Tags: neural-network, definitions

I want to know how you would define the independence of a neural network.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is so compact, but I would consider the neural networks independent from each other if they are learning on different tasks in different domains and have nothing to exchange (e.g., parameters, and structure), and the training of one network does not affect other network performance.